# Take list of processes from db and kill it CMD

Tags: database, batch-file, cmd, taskkill

I cant get this to work hope u get idea. 
I am trying to kill tasks by taking task list from my file...

```
echo off
set Taskkill_DB "C:\Users\jokbo\Desktop\CMD NEXT\Taskkill_DB.txt"
for /f tokens=* %%A in (%Taskkill_DB%) do (taskkill /F /T %%A >nul 2>&1)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only fix your code based on your existing code example.  Without seeing the actual data, I can only guess what it is in your text file.

```
echo off
set "Taskkill_DB=C:\Users\jokbo\Desktop\CMD NEXT\Taskkill_DB.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%Taskkill_DB%") do (taskkill /F /T %%A>nul 2>&1)
pause
```

Comment: @Jokbon, just want to let you know that if you read the help file for the `/F` option of the `FOR` command you could have easily seen the mistakes you were making.

Comment: @Jokbon, same goes for the `SET` command. The syntax clearly shows the usage of the equals symbol.

Comment: @Jokbon if you feel that this user assisted you in resolving your issue, please consider selecting it as the correct answer by selecting the grey tick mark on the left side of the answer.